# Is it good practice to check for existence of records before deleting them

Tags: oracle, plsql, delete

I've came across the following SQL/PLSQL while investigating a stored procedure written by someone else:

```
1. V_COUNT NUMBER(5,0);
.........
2. SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_COUNT FROM TABLE1 WHERE COL1='SOMEVALUE';
3. IF V_COUNT>0 THEN
4.   DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE COL1='SOMEVALUE';
5. END IF;
```

Isn't only the DELETE statement in the line 4 sufficient to cover all the logic that's meant with these 5 lines? I first thought maybe V_COUNT is used somewhere else, but it's not. I can't think of any good reason in making a simple delete statement so complex. Do you also think it's a bad design or is there a point that I can't see?

Comment: Note that `FROM` is optional in Oracle. And if you name your tables in the plural, then that reads very well: `DELETE widgets WHERE status = 'obsolete';`

Comment: Wouldn't this practice miss DML statements that change the data between 2nd and 3rd statements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would just `delete`.

Even if I had to only delete if there were say *exactly* 2 records, then I would add this condition to the where clause, like

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE col1='somevalue'
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE col1 = 'somevalue') = 2;
```

In all cases when writing a delete statement consider that in general the where clause is usually either

- restricting to a single row using a key;
- restricting to a set of rows using a flag/code/status column; or
- restricting to a set of rows using a range of values -- often dates.

Answer (score 1):

In generally - yes. THere is nothing to be gained by doing it like you do - not with this logic. Contrary - the example does 2 selects (to find the rows to be deleted) on the table, so it is slower.

Comment: Comment - "in generally yes" answers the "is this bad practice" question in the original post ;)

Comment: I strongly disagree with this. Don't make the database do extra work. Besides, what's to say that the count won't be different a split second after doing it. So just delete.